# Error while calling an API through ajax

Tags: magento2, javascript, rest-api, magento2.2.6, magento2-enterprise

I have added a code inside the script tag for an on-change function.

But i am m getting error like this

> Server cannot understand Content-Type HTTP header media type
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded

And the code added in phtml file is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    require(["jquery"],function($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#sellerList').change(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/rest/default/V1/Ivy/ChangeCustomPrice",
                    data: {
                        "changeRequest": {
                            "product_id": $('#sellerList').value,
                            "seller_id": <?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>
                        }
                    },

                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'application/json',
                    showLoader: true,
                    success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                        console.log("success");
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                        console.log('Error happens. Try again.');
                        console.log(errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

Can anyone say what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me

I replaced the code as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">

require(["jquery"],function($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#sellerList').change(function () {
            var changedSeller = $('#sellerList').val();
            var requestData = JSON.stringify({
                changeRequest: {
                    seller_id: changedSeller,
                    product_id: <?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: "/staging/restaurantwarecom/rest/default/V1/Ivy/ChangeCustomPrice",
                data: requestData,
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                showLoader: true,
                success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                    console.log("Success");
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('Error happens. Try again.');
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        })
    });
});
```

This might be helpful for someone.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Magento do not support urlencoded requests.

Please specify content type: Add "Content-type: application/json" to curl command and send in body parameter as {"product_id": 12, "seller_id":22}